# Saving high scores of a game to a file and then accessing them, how?

Tags: c++, file, sorting, save

I want to save all the scores of my game (a simple snake game) to a file and then read all the scores. Problem is, i dont know how to save them without knowing how many there will be.

```
 Example:
    one person plays it, gets 1200 score, it gets saved; 
2nd person plays it, gets 1000 and sees the first person's score;
3rd person plays, gets 1100 and sees the 1st and 2nd scores.
```

I've done it with an array, but doesnt really work as i want it to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

ifstream f("score.dat");
ofstream g("score.dat");

int comp(const void* e1, const void* e2){
    int f = *((int*)e1);
    int s = *((int*)e2);
    if(f>s) return 1;
    if(f<s) return -1;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int k=0;
    int n, x;
    cin >> n;
    int* v = new int[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        qsort(v, n, sizeof(int), comp);
            g << v[i] << endl;
    }

    while(f >> x){
        k++;
        cout << k << ". " << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you care about having the file open for reading and writing **at the same time** and **permanently** that we are not seeing in your sample? Or is opening these two streams as global variables a somewhat arbitrary decision?

Comment: i am not really experienced with file-work so if you know a better way around it please share :D

Comment: @Frank all i care about is being able to save all the scores of everyone playing and then sorting them and showing them after calling a function

Comment: @MickeyMoise -- `qsort(v, n, sizeof(int), comp);` -- `qsort` in a C++ program?  A simple `std::sort(v, v + n);` does all of that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, what you want is:

1. open the file for writing
2. write to the file
3. be done with writing to the file
4. open the file for reading
5. read from the file
6. be done with reading form the file.

So your code should reflect that sequence!

The key point is that you are ever only reading or writing from the file at any given moment, so the `ifstream` and the `ofstream` should never exist at the same time!

There's a few ways to go about that, but the simplest is to use functions to isolate them. Here's what that would look like in your case:

```cpp
void writeScoresToFile(int[] scores, int num_scores) {
  // g only starts existing when the function is called
  ofstream g("score.dat");

  for(int i = 0; i < num_scores; ++i ) {
    g<< v[i] << endl;
  }

  // g is destroyed. This closes the file
}


void readScoresFromFile() {
  // f only starts existing when the function is called
  ifstream f("score.dat");

  int x = 0;
  int k = 0;
  while(f>> x){
    k++;
    cout << k << ". " << x << endl;
  }

  // f is destroyed. This closes the file
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* v = new int[n];

    // ...

    // You only need to sort once, not inside the loop.
    std::sort(v, v + n);

    writeScoresToFile(v, n);

    readScoresFromFile()

    delete[] n; // <----- if there's a new, there must be a delete.
    return 0;
}
```

Btw, your code could also be better in a number of other ways, but I'm intentionally keeping things as is (apart from objectively broken things), so that you can focus on that specific part:

Comment: still, how do I make it so i input 1 score, close the console, the compiler(codeblocks), reopen the compiler, rerun the program and input another score and have it added to the file without an array?

Comment: could you please give an example as an edit to your answer cuz i've been struggling for the past 15 minutes and cant figure it out